# Write criteria to mimic join query grails

Tags: grails

I'm using grails 2.2.4 and wants to write criteria which may generates SQL like:

```
select r.value from group g, rating r where r.groupId = g.id and g.name = ?
```

Provided we've following domain structure:

```
class Group {
    String name
}

class Rating {
    Long groupId
    int value
}
```

How can I write this using grails criteria?

I was writing something like this:

```
def result = Rating.withCriteria {
    projections {
        property("value")
    }
    eq "groupId", new DetachedCriteria(Group).build {
        projections {
            property("id")
        }
        eq("name", "Group A")
    }
}
```

But from this, hibernate is generating subqueries. Any guess?

Comment: Is there a reason why you modelled this as a Long property for the id rather than a normal many-to-one association (`Group group`)? It would give the same table structure but then you could query the association in the normal way.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably change the Domain structure to be object oriented. Use associations for that: [http://grails.org/doc/2.2.4/guide/GORM.html#gormAssociation ]

Your code would then look like:

```
class Group {
    String name
}

class Rating {
    Group group
    int value
}
```

Your criteria query can be similar to this:

```
Rating.withCriteria {
    createAlias('group', '_group')
    eq('_group.name', 'Group A')
    projections {
        property('value')
    }
}
```